# Timezone problem, server uses Central Time but frontend and backend are using UTC

Tags: node.js, linux, datetime, timezone

I need assistance regarding best practices for the date/time handling of my web application.

Please excuse my lack of understanding.

This is my setup:
-Server OS: Linux server, it hosts backend and frontend
-Backend: NodeJS and express.js and moment.js
-Frontend: React and moment.js
-Database: phpMyAdmin

The web application is always opened in browsers with a central time, but I noticed that from 18h to the end of day, if I sent a moment.js date object from the client/browser, it would reach the backend with a date of the day after (with an offset of 6 hours later).

So I went to my Linux server, typed `date` in the terminal and it returned precisely the 6h+ date, which I knew was UTC. For me, and probably in my ignorance, it was obvious that I had to change the server's timezone in order to sync it with the clients that are going to make requests to it. So I did exactly that by issuing these commands in the linux terminal:

I needed this timezone:

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/Mexico_City
```

So now typing `date` in the server returns Central time. I thought that was all but it actually didn't help. The frontend kept sending the dates with what appeared to be universal time (6 hours + from central time) after this change.

Then I read that making the previous change was not going to be permanent, that it would be switched back to default upon rebooting, and that I should use this instead to make the timezone persist:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Mexico_City /etc/localtime
```

So I issued that command too, rebooted the server and checked the server date again, it returned Central time. The server is fully using Central Time now.

So I tested the web application again, and the frontend kept sending UTC instead of Central Time. Now, I'm confused because, as I mentioned, I type `date` in my linux terminal and it returns Central time. But when the frontend sends the date, it sends UTC (6h+).

So then I decided to test my backend, I created a little route to just check what time it was working with, this time I didn't use moment like I did before. Now I was using the javascript object like so: `const currentTime = new Date();`. And it returns UTC, again, not using Central time, which is the time at which the server is supposed to be working with.

So, up to this point, when I ask the date in my linux server, it returns Central Time. When I ask the backend or the frontend, it returns UTC (6h+). Out of desperation, I even went ahead and checked what time my database was using, fully knowing that my backend's time-checking route was not actually hitting the database, and ran a simple `SELECT NOW();` in phpmyadmin. It returned Central Time.

So I have the feeling that NodeJS is the one responsible for this timezone discrepancy. My question here is, what is the best practice? If I know my date objects are going to be sent frontend to backend and backend to frontend in UTC (6h+), do I change my dates to be sent (6h-) so they're in sync? What do I do to the server date?

Thanks for any input.